# auto load posts in single.php

Tags: wordpress, autoload

i'm trying to auto load all my post in single.php i have tried several plugins but neither works 
what's might be the problem i have also tried several nav-menu but i can't find what the problem is
i have the same problem in this question
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102604/enable-infinite-scroll-on-single-php
this is my single page

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package NewsCard
 */

get_header();

    newscard_layout_primary(); ?>
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

                the_post_navigation();

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->



<?php
do_action('newscard_sidebar');

 if ( $newscard_settings['newscard_footer_featured_posts_hide'] === 0 ) {

            $footer_newscard_cat = absint($newscard_settings['newscard_footer_featured_post_categories']);

            $footer_post_type = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
                'post_type' => array(
                    'post'
                ),
            );
            if ( $newscard_settings['newscard_footer_featured_latest_post'] == 'category' ) {
                $footer_post_type['category__in'] = $footer_newscard_cat;
            }

            $footer_newscard_get_featured_post = new WP_Query($footer_post_type); ?>

            <div class="container">
                <section class="featured-stories">
                    <h2 class="stories-title"><?php echo esc_html($newscard_settings['newscard_footer_featured_posts_title']); ?></h2>
                    <div class="row gutter-parent-14">
                        <?php while ($footer_newscard_get_featured_post->have_posts()) {
                            $footer_newscard_get_featured_post->the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                <div class="post-boxed">
                                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                        <div class="post-img-wrap">
                                            <div class="featured-post-img">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url(get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full')); ?>');"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="entry-meta category-meta">
                                                <div class="cat-links"><?php the_category(' '); ?></div>
                                            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
                                        </div><!-- .post-img-wrap -->
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="post-content">
                                        <?php if ( !has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                            <div class="entry-meta category-meta">
                                                <div class="cat-links"><?php the_category(' '); ?></div>
                                            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">', '</a></h3>' ); ?>
                                        <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) { ?>
                                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                                <?php newscard_posted_on(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div><!-- .post-content -->
                                </div><!-- .post-boxed -->
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-6 .col-lg-3 -->
                        <?php }
                        // Reset Post Data
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .row -->
                </section><!-- .featured-stories -->
            </div><!-- .container -->
        <?php } 
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: What does "auto load" mean in this context? Do you simply mean "I want to show all posts in my single post template"?

Comment: If you are trying to show all posts in your footer, set 'posts_per_page' to -1.